# Looking for a Free Lexical Analyser

Tags: computational-linguistics, software, analysis

I need to do a quantitative analysis to  a medieval text. I need to get some basic information like the total number of the words, their frequencies and the concordances.

Does anyone know about a free  Lexical Analyser software for Windows 7 to wor11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20n advance.

Comment: **$ wc medieval.txt > wordcount.txt**

Comment: thank you but i've got windows.

Comment: You can still get Unix apps that work on Windows. Or even on DOS. Free.

Comment: Have you tried something like this?: http://textalyser.net/ Out of curiosity, what text are you analysing?

Comment: thank you, i'm going to take a look. i'm working with the Portuguese translation of the Queste del Saint Graal, Post-Vulgate.

Comment: Do a search for concordance software. You'll find plenty, some free.

Comment: looks like a simple task. i'd say take about six weeks to learn perl then write the tool yourself. it'll be worth it.

Comment: [`wc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_(Unix)) is not a *[lexical analyser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)*.

Answer (score 4):

There are many software applications for linguistic analysis listed at [LinguistList's software page](http://linguistlist.org/sp/GetWRListings.cfm?WRAbbrev=Software), including lexical analysis tools and, probably what you're after, concordance software (and lots of other fun stuff too). Most are free.

I suspect that the first one in the list, 'Simple concordance program' will do what you want.

Additional: here's an even better [list of text analysis tools](https://digitalresearchtools.pbworks.com/w/page/17801708/Text%20Analysis%20Tools).